# Period of a pendulum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, physics

> Consider the pendulum problem
>
> $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\sin(x)=0$
>
> $\frac{dx}{dt}(0)=v_0=0$
>
> $x(0)=x_0$
>
> Show that the period $T=\displaystyle2\int_{-x_o}^{x_0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\cos(x)-\cos(x_0)}}$

Why do I get: $T=\displaystyle2\int_{-x_o}^{x_0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2(\cos(x)-\cos(x_0)})}$, is the question wrong, can you check my steps please !

$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\sin(x)=0\implies\frac{dx}{dt}(\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\sin(x))=0$

but $\frac{dx}{dt}(\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\sin(x))=\frac{d}{dt}\Big(\frac12(\frac{dx}{dt})^2-\cos(x)\Big)$

Hence

$\frac12(\frac{dx}{dt})^2-\cos(x)=C$,$\qquad$$\text{C is Constant}$

With the initial value I obtain;

$C=-\cos(x_0)$ Therefore;

$\frac12(\frac{dx}{dt})^2=\cos(x)-\cos(x_0)\implies (\frac{dx}{dt})=-\sqrt{2(\cos(x)-\cos(x_0))}$

Sign is negative because $x$ is decreasing, with separation of variables it becomes to:

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{T/4}dt=-\int_{x_0}^{0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2(\cos(x)-\cos(x_0))}}\implies T=2\int_{-x_o}^{x_0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2(\cos(x)-\cos(x_0)})}$

Comment: You derivation is correct, the question is missing the $\sqrt{2}$ factor.